# How to automate the creation of "this." variables in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, automation, this

Working on Javascript and more particulary Angular, I regulary use the `this.` syntax.

I'd like to know if I could concatenate variables to obtain a `this.` variable.
For example is that is doable ?

```
let variable = 'variable1';
let test = 'this.' + variable
test = false
```

My goal would be to automate the creation of `this.` variables.

Thank you very much for your help !

Comment: Do you mean like `let test = this[variable]`? Could you explain a bit more what your end-goal is? To e.g. loop over a structure, and assign each element to `this`? `[['a', 123], ['b', true]].forEach(([key, val], i) => this[key] = val); console.log(this.a); ` gives `123`

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no reason to do this. With your way you are just initializing strings in variables and then overwrite them with a boolean.

In my opinion its good for readability and understanding to see "this.", which means the following is from this class you are in at the moment. If there isn't proper code highlighting it can be confusing without it. I think you just need to get comfortable with it, but doing something like you want to feels like working around the language and not with it.